# Empty POST Request from android to php

Tags: php, android, post

I have a claim text and I want to sent it from android to server but it show that "W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" but there is no

code and  m sure that the query is correct.
It put in database an empty row and it show no description for sql query.
type of claim row in db is varchar (255).
I used post methode in php file.
I tried the same thing with another activity (username, passwork) and it works correctly.

Do anyone know how can I solve it ? Thank  you .

```
  public class ReclamActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
 private EditText editTextClaim;
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reclam);
    editTextClaim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextClaim);
    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }
    private void submit(){
    final String claim = editTextClaim.getText().toString().trim();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_Claim,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("claim", claim);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I tried to switch and try http client but I did not find any result.

Comment: do you have the responce?

Comment: show the full stacktrace and show the line where the error appears

Comment: no in database it put another row but empty in php file I put   $claim=$_Post['claim'];

Comment: it is the full code and there is an error just when I put     Log.d(TAG, "#############################" + response); in public void onResponse to see if response is empty or not.

Comment: Did you try using `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest`?